# Spring Boot Thymeleaf & Flying Saucer PDF display a URL with hyphen correctly

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, flying-saucer

My PDF contains a URL with a hyphen symbol in text form. When I copy the URL directly from the PDF by marking it and when the hyphen symbol is at the end of line then the symbol is gone after paste.

I have the following html:

```
...
<p>test test test test 123 test test 123 test test xy 
  <a style="color:black;text-decoration:none" th:href="${myURL}" th:text="${myURL}"></a>
</p
...
```

Result is:
[image]

But after copy pasting I get the url without hyphen: https://sec2mms.hansatonich.at/test.t.ozkq/

What am I missing here?

Comment: Weird. And if you click on the URL, it opens correctly?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Yes it does open correctly. Cause the href is used.

Comment: I am facing exactly same problem today, will post answer soon!

Answer (score 1):

I use thymeleaf and flying soucer in sprint-boot application (azure function) to generate PDF. In my case it was not exactly hyphen-minus character, it was "non-breaking hyphen", probably it was due to some copy paste. I used https://unicodelookup.com/ to check its unicode and that is how I was able to find it. Replaced it with "-" to fix the problem.

[image]

Below is unicode for "-" (hyphen-minus), this is what we need generally.
[image]

non-breaking hyphen, is not visible at lot of places. Below is the way it is shown in notepad++

[image]